How to reduce to reduce to the case where the class $C$ is a set in this model theory exercise
I am working through the book "A course in model theory" by K. Tent and M. Ziegler. I am having issues with exercise 2.1 where we are given some class $C$ of $L$ - structures:

Let Th($C$) = {ϕ | $A$ $\models$ ϕ for all $A$ ∈ $C$} be the theory of $C$. Then $M$
is a model of Th($C$) if and only if $M$ is elementarily equivalent to an
ultraproduct of elements of $C$.

I managed to prove it under the assumption that $C$ is a set but I am having trouble reducing to this case. I checked in the appendix of the book, where they give solutions to the exercises, but they just state that you can reduce to the case where $C$ is a set, like it is a fact.
I guess the idea is that since we only care about the structures in $C$ modulo elementary equivalence, we want to pick one representative for each class of elementary equivalent structures in $C$ and obtain a set out of that. But I don't see what axioms would allow us to do that. I'm honestly not too familiar with the concept of classes, so I may just be missing something trivial here.

At what stage in your proof do you need to assume $C$ is a set?

@AlexKruckman I (and the book author) use C as the index set for the ultraproduct. And you can only define filters on sets, not proper classes

Oh, I see. I would interpret "an ultraproduct of elements of $C$" to mean "an ultraproduct, where each of the factors is in $C$". Then you can construct the ultraproduct by choosing one structure in $C$ satisfying each sentence true in $M$ and choosing an appropriate ultrafilter on the set of such sentences.

@AlexKruckman How would you choose one structure for each sentence true in $M$? To me this seems even harder

I mean, I know of course you can do it with a similar argument like before, but I don't think you can get around making that argument.

Yes, you're right. I guess my point is that if you've already accepted the principle that you can make a choice from each of a set-index family of non-empty proper classes (e.g. by the trick in Noah's answer), then you can give a solution to the exercise that doesn't involve explicitly reducing to the case where $C$ is a set, sweeping the details of how to implement the argument in ZFC under the rug as usual.

@AlexKruckman I see. For my curiosity: What ultrafilter would you choose on the set of all sentences? My initial idea when trying to solve the problem was similar, but I couldn't see a natural way to define the filter

Let $T$ be the complete theory of $M$. For every  $\varphi\in T$, let $X_\varphi$ be the set of all sentences in $T$ which entail $\varphi$. This family has FIP (since $\varphi_1\land\dots\land \varphi_n\in X_{\varphi_1}\cap\dots\cap X_{\varphi_n}$), so it extends to an ultrafilter $U$. Let $N_\varphi$ be in $C$ satisfying $\varphi$. Then the ultraproduct $\prod_{\varphi\in T} N_\varphi / U$ satisfies $T$, because for all $\psi\in T$, $X_\psi\subseteq {\varphi\in T\mid N_\varphi\models \psi}$ is in the ultrafilter.

Use the cumulative hierarchy! There must be some ordinal $\alpha$ such that for every $\mathcal{M}\in C$, there is an $\mathcal{M}'\in C\cap V_\alpha$ with $\mathcal{M}\equiv\mathcal{M}'$; this is simply because there are only set-many theories in the relevant language. So we can just replace $C$ with $C\cap V_\alpha$ for the least such $\alpha$. (Incidentally, note that this doesn't involve the axiom of choice at all, or any particulars about first-order logic; the same trick works without choice and for any set-sized logic.)

I see, so essentially we take the set of all theories of $L$ and use the axiom of separation to be left with only the theories that have a model in $C$. Neat! I was going down a rabbit hole of trying to define equivalence classes on proper classes and/or using some version of choice. Odd that choice is not needed at all

Alternatively, if $|L|=\kappa$, every $L$-structure is elementarily equivalent to one whose domain is the ordinal $\kappa$ by Löweheim-Skolem, and the class of all structures with a fixed domain is a set. @user9620780

@AlexKruckman True, but that uses nontrivial facts about FOL.

Yes, but it avoids using foundation. :)

@AlexKruckman ... oh dang. That's a point!
